# IntelliSens doesn't detect type property while updating immuable value

Tags: f#

While defining an inventory system for an RPG game, I came across an odd issue. So, what I'm trying to do is to add items a player would get from a shop. While adding, I'm make sure not to go over the weight limit and will increase the quantity of an item if it were already in my inventory bag, otherwise I'll plainly add the item.

So far so good, this looks pretty sane. My issue is when I'm updating my abstract class, IntelliSens tries to tell me that I don't have that property define for the type that I'm using. Actually, it can't find any of the property of the abstract class. Could be a bad mistake, but I've been scratching my head over this for quite some time and I would like some support !

**UPDATE**

here's the compiling error:The type 'InventoryItem' does not contain a field 'Quantity'..\InventoryItems.fs 188

```
    [<AbstractClass>]
    type InventoryItem() =

    abstract member ItemName : string 

    abstract member ItemDescription : string 

    abstract member ItemWeight : float<kg> 

    abstract member ItemPrice : float<usd> 

    abstract member Quantity : int with get, set


    let makeBagItemsDistinct (bag: InventoryItem array) = 
    bag |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toArray

    type Inventory = {
        Bag : InventoryItem array
        Weight: float<kg>
    }

    with 
        member x.addItem (ii: InventoryItem): Inventory = 
            if x.Weight >= MaxWeight <> true then x 
            elif (x.Weight + ii.ItemWeight) >= MaxWeight then x
            else 
                let oItemIndex = x.Bag |> Array.tryFindIndex(fun x -> x = ii)
                match oItemIndex with 
                | Some index -> 
                    // There already an item of this type in the bag
                    let item = x.Bag |> Array.find(fun x -> x = ii)
                    let newBag = 
                        x.Bag
                        |> Array.filter((<>) item)
                        |> Array.append [| { item with Quantity = item.Quantity +ii.Quantity |]
                        |> makeBagItemsDistinct

                    let inventory = { x with Bag = newBag }
                    { inventory with Weight = inventory.Weight + item.ItemWeight }
                | None -> 
                    let newBag = x.Bag |> Array.append [|ii|] |> makeBagItemsDistinct
                    let inventory = { x with Bag = newBag }
                    { inventory with Weight = inventory.Weight + ii.ItemWeight }
```

Comment: First, your indentation looks off, please correct it. Second, please explain what error you're getting, where, when, or otherwise how do you know that "it's not working".

Comment: I made some changes @FyodorSoikin. Like I had mentioned earlier, the compiler doesn't seem to see my Quantity field inside the the InventoryItem abstract class

Comment: Your indentation is still off. And "doesn't seem to see" is not a good description of a problem.

Comment: I think something might be mangling your formatting when you paste here, because this code has many whitespace issues from the very beginning that stop it from compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [with keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/copy-and-update-record-expressions) works with records only. You are trying to use it on a class.

You might want to switch to a [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/records) if you want to always copy `InventoryItem` on change, like you are already doing with `Inventory`.

Comment: How would I have to go if I still wanted to update an abstract class ? I do understand what you're saying but surely, there's a way ?

Comment: If you need to copy on change then you could have an abstract `With` method that clones the object and has optional parameters for changing certain fields in the clone. But each child class would have to implement its own `With` method. It's a lot of boilerplate. I would reconsider the use of an abstract class, or even classes at all, if C# interop isn't required.

Comment: Hmmm, came across this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/object-expressions
That would have made a better answer than what you've provided me. It's exactly the functionality I was looking for. I understand why using DU and records is great in F# but I was looking for an answer covering creation of my type.